# How to select end date greater that start date (date time picker)

Tags: jquery, datetime, jquery-ui, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

I want to select the end DateTime greater than the starting date in DateTime picker.

Currently, I am getting to start DateTime and ending DateTime.

Suppose, I selected the current date with time 12:00 pm, now end Date should be the current date with time 1:00 pm.

I want something like below

**Example**

Starting date and time:--- **2019-11-06 12:00**
Ending date and time : ---- **2019-11-06 1:00**

Here is my code

```js
$(function () {
    $("#txtFrom").datetimepicker({
        format: 'Y-m-d H:i',
        minDate: 0,
        onChangeDateTime:startDate
    });
    function startDate(selected){
            var dt = new Date(selected);
            dt.setDate(dt.getDate() + 1);
           
            $("#txtTo").datetimepicker("option", "minDate", dt);
}

    $("#txtTo").datetimepicker({
        format: 'Y-m-d H:i',
       
        onChangeDateTime:endDate
    });
   
    function endDate(selected){
        var dt = new Date(selected);    
            dt.setDate(dt.getDate() - 1);

            $("#txtFrom").datetimepicker("option", "maxDate", dt);
}


  
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
   <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
   <meta charset="utf-8">

   <title>Home</title>
   <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"></script>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-datetimepicker/2.5.4/jquery.datetimepicker.css">
   <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-datetimepicker/2.5.4/build/jquery.datetimepicker.full.js"></script>


 </head>
 <body>
  
 <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<tr>
    <td>
        From:
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" id="txtFrom" />
    </td>
    <td>
        &nbsp;
    </td>
    <td>
        To:
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" id="txtTo" />
    </td>
</tr>
</table> 

<!-- <input name="startDate" type="text" id="txtFrom"/> -->

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Plugin you are using for date time picker has problem regarding set minTime.
even in their demo minTime functionality is not working.already multiple user submit issue for the same.if you want to change in plugin code or  more detail regarding it you can get it from here https://github.com/xdan/datetimepicker/issues/377